# Apache Solr : How to access and index files from another server

Tags: solr, lucene

Solr version :: 6.6.1

I am new to the Apache Solr and currently exploring how to use this technology to search in the PDF files.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-tikaentityprocessor

I am able to index the PDF files using the "BinFileDataSource" for the PDF files within the same server as shown in the below example.

Now i want to know if there is a way to change the baseDir pointing to the folder present under a different server.

Please suggest an example to access the PDF files from another server. How will i write the path in the baseDir attribute.

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource"/> <!--Local filesystem-->
  <document>
    <entity name="K2FileEntity" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" dataSource="null"
            recursive = "true"
            baseDir="C:/solr-6.6.1/server/solr/core_K2_Depot/Depot" fileName=".*pdf" rootEntity="false">

            <field column="file" name="id"/>
            <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastmodified" />

              <entity name="pdf" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" onError="skip"
                      url="${K2FileEntity.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text">

                <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
                <field column="dc:format" name="format" meta="true"/>
                <field column="text" name="text"/>

              </entity>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer from the solr-user mailing list.

Just change the baseDir to the folder present on another server (SMB paths works directly):

```
baseDir="\\CLDServer2\RemoteK2Depot"
```